# Why is the derivative of a tensor not a tensor (in general)?

Tags: tensors

I see that the need to apply the product rule when using curvilinear coordinates results in a term for the derivative of the coefficients that still follows tensor transformation rules, and that it is the derivative of the bases vectors that is the problem. But can I have that product rule spelled out in tensor notation with a plain English explanation of what in the second term breaks the transformation rules for tensors?

For instance what makes the second term below not tensorial specifically?

$$\partial_{\mu'} T_{\nu'}=\frac{ \partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}} \partial_\mu T_\nu +\frac{ \partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}T_\nu \partial_\mu\left(\frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}\right)  $$

In there the $\partial \mu$ transforms like

$$\partial_{\mu'}=\frac{ \partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\partial_{\mu}
$$

And the idea is to transform $$\partial_{\mu}T_\nu   $$

Is it the $\mu$ index or both? What summation in that second summand messes things up and why?

Comment: Which derivative are referring to?  If $M$ is a manfiold with connection $\nabla$ and $T$ is a rank $(k,l)$-tensor field on $M$ then $\nabla T$ is rank $(k, l+1)$-tensor field on $M$.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make sure everything that is an index is an index, and every prime is attached to the symbol it is priming?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Ty for bringing this up. I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so let's say that $T$ is a one-form as you have there, and let's make $$S_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu T_\nu$$explicit. Is it true that the relation $$S_{\mu'\nu'} ={\color{blue}{\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}S_{\mu\nu}}}$$holds? Absolutely not! Because $$S_{\mu'\nu'} = \partial_{\mu'}T_{\nu'} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}T_\nu\right) = {\color{blue}{\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}S_{\mu\nu}}} + {\color{red}{\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial^2 x^\nu}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^{\nu'}}T_\nu}}. $$

Comment: So it's not like looking at the part in red there is a concrete mismatch in the indices, or that there is a second partial derivative, but that the mere fact of having anything at all after the part in blue will mess things up no matter what it is (other than zero)?

Comment: I just applied the product rule, so we indeed get a second derivative term. But indeed, the point is that having anything other than the term in blue messes up the tensor transformation law. So "$\partial T$" is not a tensor.

Answer (score 2):

The formula
$$\partial_{\mu'} T_{\nu'}=\frac{ \partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}} \partial_\mu T_\nu +\frac{ \partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\,T_\nu\,\partial_\mu\left(\frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}\right)  $$
is not tensorial
because of the presence of the second term. If you take instead of the partial derivative $\partial_\mu$ the covariant derivative
$$
\nabla_\mu T_\nu=\partial_\mu T_\nu-\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}T_\rho
$$
you get
$$\tag{1}
\nabla_{\mu'} T_{\nu'}=\frac{ \partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}} \nabla_\mu T_\nu
$$
which is how a second rank tensor transforms. The [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Transformation_law_under_change_of_variable) that make this work obey
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{\mu '}_{\alpha '\beta '} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^{\gamma}}\frac{\partial^2x^\gamma}{\partial x^{\beta '}\partial x^{\alpha '}}+\frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^\gamma}\frac{\partial x^{\sigma}}{\partial x^{\alpha '}}\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial x^{\beta '}}\Gamma^{\gamma}_{\sigma p}.
\end{equation}
You can read equation (1) as
$$
\nabla_{\mu'} T_{\nu'}=\frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}} \nabla_{\mu'} T_\nu\,.
$$
In other words, unlike the partial derivative $\partial_{\mu'}$ the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\mu'}$ can be "pulled through" the term
$$
\frac{ \partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}
$$
as if that was a constant. That's the whole point of introducing the covariant derivative.

Comment: Would there be  Christoffel symbols to transform to spherical coordinates from rectangular?

Comment: Of course. Just scroll down in [this link](http://www.einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/dictionary/25-christoffel-symbol) .

Comment: Most things about this stuff I started to learn from [Sean Carroll](https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/~george/ay21/readings/carroll-gr-textbook.pdf).