# Showing that a derivative of a contravariant tensor is not a tensor

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

If $T_i$ is a covariant tensor of order 1 and $Z$ and $Z'$ denote old and new coordinate systems, such that $T_{i'} = T_{i} \frac{\partial Z^{i}}{\partial Z^{i'}}=T_i J^i_{i'}$ then I show that $\frac{\partial T_i}{\partial Z^j}$ is not a tensor this way:

\begin{align*}\frac{\partial T_{i'}}{\partial Z^{j'}} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial Z^{j'}} \left[ T_i\left(Z\left(Z'\right)\right) J^{i'}_i \right]\\
&=\frac{\partial T_i}{\partial Z^k} \frac{\partial  Z^k}{\partial Z^{j'}} J^{i}_{i'} + T_i \frac{\partial J^i_{i'}}{\partial Z^{j'}}\\
&= \frac{\partial T_i}{\partial Z^k} J^k_{j'} J^i_{i'} + T_i \frac{\partial^2 Z^i}{\partial Z^{j'} \partial Z^{i'}}
\end{align*}
And due to the last term, this does not transform as a covariant tensor and I am done (hopefully). However, when I apply the same procedure to a contravariant tensor $T^i$:

\begin{align*}\frac{\partial T^{i'}}{\partial Z^{j'}} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial Z^{j'}} \left[ T^i\left(Z\left(Z'\right)\right) J^{i'}_{i} \right]\\
&=\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial Z^k} \frac{\partial  Z^k}{\partial Z^{j'}} J_{i}^{i'} + T^i \frac{\partial J_i^{i'}}{\partial Z^{j'}}\\
&= \frac{\partial T^i}{\partial Z^k} J^k_{j'} J_i^{i'} + T^i \frac{\partial}{\partial Z^{j'}}\left( \frac{\partial Z^{i'}}{\partial Z^i}\right)
\end{align*}
However, the last term is different, nothing really prevents me from switching the order of partials, getting:

\begin{align*}T^i \frac{\partial}{\partial Z^{j'}}\left( \frac{\partial Z^{i'}}{\partial Z^i}\right) &= T^i \frac{\partial}{\partial Z^{i}}\left( \frac{\partial Z^{i'}}{\partial Z^{j'}}\right) \\
&= T^i \frac{\partial}{\partial Z^{i}}\left( \delta^{i'}_{j'} \right) = 0\end{align*}

which would imply that the $\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial Z^j}$ transforms as a tensor.

What is my mistake?

**Note**: this is from page-82 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor Calculus Book, Exercise 91 and a relevant question about the same problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450386/initial-step-in-proving-that-a-partial-derivative-of-a-tensor-is-not-a-tensor) but without answer to this particular mistake i am making. Another relevant question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391034/why-is-the-derivative-of-a-tensor-not-a-tensor-in-general/4391154#4391154) but it stops shy of the switching derivatives which seem to render the expression zero.

Comment: Why couldn't you interchange the derivatives in the first expression?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I can but it does not result in Kronecker delta like in the second case and therefore unless some special case, there is no reason for the term to disappear in the first case, in the second case I did something bad but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will change you notation a bit, I find $Z$ and $Z'$ confusing. Sorry!

Let's use $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ for the first coordinate system and $y=(y^1,\dots,y^n)$ for the second. The confusion comes from the term $$\partial_{x^i}\left(\partial_{y^j}x^k\right)$$
but on the face of it, this expression does not make much sense: inside the parenthesis we are considering a function $x^k(y)$, and we take its derivative with respect to $y^j$. But then what does it mean to take the derivative along $x^i$?

The answer comes from noticing that the actual expression coming from the change of coordinates gives $$\partial_{x^i}\left(\partial_{y^j}x^k\Bigr|_{y(x)}\right)$$
and we use the chain rule to get $$\partial_{x^i}\left(\partial_{y^j}x^k\Bigr|_{y(x)}\right)=\partial_{y^l}\partial_{y^j}x^k\,\partial_{x^i}y^l$$
which should show that indeed $\partial_{x^i}T^j(x)$ is not a tensor.

An easy one-dimensional example: let $y(x)=(x−1)^2$, so that $x(y)=\sqrt{y}+1$. Near $0$, these are diffeomorphisms (inverse to each other). Now, what happens if we coumpute $\partial_x\left(\partial_yx\Bigr|_{y(x)}\right)$? We get $\partial_yx(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$, so $(\partial_yx)(y(x))=\frac{1}{2(x−1)}$. When you take the next derivative, we finally arrive at $-\frac{1}{2(x−1)^2}$. If you could switch the derivatives, you would instead get $0$.

Intuitively, the reason why you cannot switch the derivatives in the expression $\partial_x\partial_y$, is that *$y$ depends on $x$*.

Comment: I have tried this in a way but arrived to the same result. Why cannot you switch the derivatives? Because if I can, I get from your 2nd expression: 
$\partial_{y^j}\left[\partial_{x^i} x^k(y^1(\vec{x}),\ldots,y^N(\vec{x})) \right] = \partial_{y^j}\left[ \partial_{y^m}x^k \partial_{x^i} y^m \right] = \partial_{y^j}\left[ J^x_y J^y_x \right] = \partial_{y^j}\left[ \delta^k_i \right]=0$ where those $J$ are jacobians of mutually inverse transforms, so either i am not allowed to switch the derivatives (but why?) or i am abusing chain rule in a way I am not seeing.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see the math formula in your comment. Anyway, you should get something like $T(y)_k\,\partial_{x^i}y^j\,\partial_{x^l}\partial_{x^j}y^k\,\partial_{y^j}x^l$ which simplifies (as the two Jacobians are inverses of each other) to $T(y)_k\,\partial_{x^i}\partial_{x^j}y^k$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: ok, I see it now. The point is that you cannot switch the derivatives. Consider this example: let $y(x)=(x-1)^2$, so that $x(y)=\sqrt{y}+1$. Near $0$, these are diffeomorphisms (inverse to each other). Now, what happens if we coumpute $\partial_x\left(\partial_yx\Bigr|_{y(x)}\right)$? We get $\partial_yx(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$, so $(\partial_yx)(y(x))=\frac{1}{2(x-1)}$. When you take the next derivative, we finally arrive at $-\frac{1}{2(x-1)^2}$. If you could switch the derivatives, you would instead get $0$. The point is that in the expression $\partial_x\partial_y$, *$y$ depends on $x$*.

Comment: @atapaka I will integrate my last comment into the answer, I guess it will be easier to find if other people are interested.